# How can I integrate nightingale with the Unity sound menu?

Tags: 12.10, sound, music

I have tried going to dconf-editor and adding it to the preferred and interested media playered list. While it does show up in the sound meni the pause, next track and previous track have no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done without patching nightingale. I recommend trying to contact the devs, or add a ticket to nightingale's bug tracker :)